# Docusign responsive layout

Tags: docusignapi

Actually I am using REST API (DocuSign) to sign on the documents in our application. But our application going to change responsive layout. Is there way to get responsive layout for DocuSing screens into our application.

Please help me on this ASAP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Docusign is what it is -- no way to specify a different layout scheme for DocuSign screens.